# Z3 Checking whether all values in array are unique

Tags: z3, smt

So I'm trying to check whether all values in an array is unique with the following Z3 code.

```
(declare-const A (Array Int Int))
(declare-const n Int)
(assert (forall ((i Int) (j Int)) (and (and (and (>= i 0) (< i n)) (and (>= j 0) (< j n)))
                                       (implies (= (select A i) (select A j)) (= i j)))))
(check-sat)
```

I'm quite new to Z3 so I don't quite understand the grammar and stuff, but can anyone tell me whether this code is right, and if not, where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as you wrote is `unsat`, because it says whenever `0 <= i < n` and `0 <= j < n`, if `A[i] = A[j]`, then `i = j`. There is no array and a particular `n` you can pick to satisfy this constraint.

What you really want to write is the following instead:

```
(declare-const A (Array Int Int))
(declare-const n Int)
(assert (forall ((i Int) (j Int)) (implies (and (>= i 0) (< i n)
                                                (>= j 0) (< j n)
                                                (= (select A i) (select A j)))
                                           (= i j))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The above says `If` it's the case that `i` and `j` are within bounds, and array elements are the same, then `i` must equal `j`. And this variant would be satisifiable for any `n`; and indeed here's what z3 reports:

```
sat
(
  (define-fun n () Int
    0)
  (define-fun A () (Array Int Int)
    ((as const (Array Int Int)) 0))
)
```

But note that z3 simply picked `n = 0`, which made it easy to satisfy the formula. Let's make sure we get a more interesting model, by adding:

```
(assert (> n 2))
```

Now we get:

```
sat
(
  (define-fun n () Int
    3)
  (define-fun A () (Array Int Int)
    (lambda ((x!1 Int))
  (let ((a!1 (ite (and (<= 1 x!1) (not (<= 2 x!1))) 7 8)))
    (ite (<= 1 x!1) (ite (and (<= 1 x!1) (<= 2 x!1)) 6 a!1) 5))))
)
```

and we see that z3 picked the array to have 3 elements with distinct values at positions we care about.

Note that this sort of reasoning with quantifiers is a soft-spot for SMT solvers; while z3 is able to find models for these cases, if you keep adding quantified axioms you'll likely get `unknown` as the answer, or z3 (or any other SMT solver for that matter) will take longer and longer time to respond.